# CSS circle with different results

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've this see a screengrab and blue circle is ok but grey circle appear funny even with two same css and js? I would appreciate how to correct a grey circle? I'm using both a same css and js but grey faired poorly.

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/circle.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/circle.png)

CSS3

```
  button {
      height: 90px;
      width: 90px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 3px solid #fff;
      background-color:#003F5F;
  }

  button:hover {
      background-color:#FFCC05; /*47C3D2*/
  }

  buttongrey {
      height: 90px;
      width: 90px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 3px solid #fff;
      background-color:#a8a9a2;
      }

  buttongrey:hover {
      background-color:#FFCC05;
  }
```

Javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
  });
  $("buttongrey").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
  });
  </script>
```

UPDATE: HTML5

```
  <div data-role="content"> <div class="content_index"><!--START CONTENT and another at the END -->
          <div id="content_index_left" align="center">
          <ul data-role="listview">
              <li><a href="#page1"><button><img style="vertical-align: middle" src="images/index_10.svg" width="80%" alt="" title="" border="0" class="shadow" /></button></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page1"><span class="bold_index">Ten tips</span></a></li><br />

              <li><a href="#page2"><button><img style="vertical-align: middle" src="images/index_triadic.svg" width="90%" alt="" title="" border="0" class="shadow" /></button></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page2"><span class="bold_index">Triadic Exchange</span></a></li><br />

              <li><a href="#page6"><buttongrey><img style="vertical-align: middle" src="images/index_deafculture.svg" width="80%" alt="" title="" border="0" class="shadow" /></button></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page6"><span class="bold_index">Deaf Culture</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          </div> 
          <div id="content_index_right" align="center">           
          <ul data-role="listview">
              <li><a href="#page4"><button><img style="vertical-align: middle" src="images/index_video.svg" width="80%" alt="" title="" border="0" class="shadow" /></button></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page4"><span class="bold_index">Video</span></a></li><br />

              <li><a href="#page3"><button><img style="vertical-align: middle" src="images/index_examples.svg" width="85%" alt="" title="" border="0" class="shadow" /></button></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page3"><span class="bold_index">Examples</span></a></li><br />

              <li><a href="#page5"><buttongrey><img style="vertical-align: middle" src="images/index_disability.svg" width="90%" alt="" title="" border="0" class="shadow" /></button></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page5"><span class="bold_index">Disability Rights</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
      </div></div>
```

Comment: are you actually using buttongrey tags or should you be using the css selector .buttongrey? Also could you post the HTML?

Comment: You don't have a "hover" class defined. This is different from the ":hover" pseudo-class.

Comment: Ok How do I include a "hover" class defined? It is for iphone app.

Comment: .hover { ... }, just like any other CSS class.

Comment: You should really be using CSS backgrounds for your buttons, not inline images.

Comment: <buttongrey> is not a valid HTML tag.

Comment: `hover` is nothing you should use on a touch device. You don't have a mouse.

Comment: @Diodeus says it is not a valid tag. How do I fix it? The blue button with yellow hover. Grey button with yellow hover. How do I make all buttons same size?

Comment: Instead of using <a href="#page5"><span class="bold_index">, just use: <a href="#page5" class="bold_index"> and skip the SPAN completely.

Comment: Or point me to a right site where I can get circle scripts through internet with two different colours. Its so hard to find one that will work on iOS6 stimulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html tag buttongrey doesn't exist !!
For me this is the solution :

HTML :

```
<li>
  <a href="#page6">
     <button class="grey">
        <img style="vertical-align: middle" src="images/index_deafculture.svg" width="80%" alt="" title="" border="0" class="shadow" />
     </button>
  </a>
</li>
```

CSS :

```
.grey {
      height: 90px;
      width: 90px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 3px solid #fff;
      background-color:#a8a9a2;
 }

.grey:hover {
     background-color:#FFCC05;
 }​
```